# Exclamation mark problem on dll?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, c#-4.0

I've added a DLL to my project, written with visual studio 2005.
After I did so, an exclamation mark appears nearby the added DLL.

I want to not having this exclamation mark because I'm assume its reflect about a problem.

A friend of me added this DLL to his project on this computer and everything worked well, so I assume I didn't added it well nor there is a problem in my visual studio/computer.

Any ideas how to handle it?

Answer (score 100):

I had the same problem when Target framework of destination project and the version of references was different. After I've changed it Project properties, it worked.

Comment: What does the yellow exclamation mean?  My projects could compile just fine.

Comment: Same issue here - new project was version 4.5 and referenced version was 4.5.1. Thanks!

Comment: Your strategy is best used when a Visual Studio solution has a *project reference* to another project in the same solution. In that case, it's rather easy to access the properties of the referenced project (the one with the yellow exclamation in references) and change its target framework setting. You wouldn't necessarily want to change the target framework of the project that makes the reference, however, because that can cause other projects to fall out of sync. If a project references a compiled DLL, you would need new ver of that DLL or would need to modify target framework of source proj.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that VS can't find the assembly. Make sure it's in a location that is accessible to you, and compare this with your friend's. E.g., is it on a co-worker's machine that may be turned off at certain times? Is it on a network drive?

I'd suggest making a local copy of the file and seeing if the problem is solved.

Question is a possible duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655763/referenced-assembly-wont-load).